# GitLab redirects to page 422 upon installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise, passenger, gitlab

I installed GitLab by following their [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html) page. The server would be accessible as http://foobar.com/gitlab. I have passenger+apache installation. (unicorn is also running). After installation finished, it loads the login page, when I type the default username/password(root/5iveL!fe), it redirects to a 422 page with following error:

```
422
The change you requested was rejected.
```

I thought maybe there is something wrong with password, tried to [reset password from console](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/security/reset_root_password.html) but when running `gitlab-rails console production` and `sudo -u git -H gitlab-rails console production` I got the following error:

```
ls: cannot access /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log: No such file or directory
chpst: fatal: unknown user/group: -U
```

Since the first error is cause there is no log file, I manually created a log file but after running the command i got the following error:

```
chpst: fatal: unable to setgroups: permission denied
```

I don't know what to do else. Also in production.log, it complains about CSR Token not being valid. Which I assume means I am not supplying the correct password, but that is the password that was given by GitLab installation.

Also might be relevant, I used this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924644/gitlab-in-a-subdirectory-with-apache-and-passenger) to configure apache. Apache vhost portion for GitLab looks like this

```
 35  ProxyPass→→ → → /gitlab/→ http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab/
 36  ProxyPassReverse →/gitlab/→ http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab/
 37  ProxyPass→→ → → /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab
 38  ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab
 39  ProxyPass→→ → → /assets→→ http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab/assets
 40  ProxyPassReverse /assets→ http://127.0.0.1:8080/gitlab/assets
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since nobody has answered, I will post my solution so that anyone else might find it beneficial. 
The problem was with https. If I turned off https option in gitlab.yml (https: false) then I was able to login. The detailed solution can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-ssl.conf). I had to add the following in my virtualhosts(since I have one for foobar.com.conf and foobar.com-ssl.conf) file.

In foobar.com.conf File I had to add:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
```

and in foobar.com-ssl.conf I had to add:

```
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
```

For more troubleshooting problems visit [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticitycant-get-past-login-pageredirected-to-login-page).